# Git command to check if a remote branch is brand new or has had any commits to it?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, branch, webhooks

I set up a Bitbucket webhook which is triggered on any push to a specific repository, which includes creating a branch. What I need to do is ignore any time the webhook is triggered specifically by a new branch being created. The issue is when someone creates a branch locally and commits to that local branch, once they push that local branch remote it triggers the webhook on that branch for the first time, essentially causing the same behavior as when a branch is initially created remotely without any commits.

My initial idea was to use git `name-rev --name-only <commit sha>` on the latest commit for a branch. This spits out the branch name on a commit, so I could compare the current branch name to the result. The problem is commits of pull requests don't work super well with the command, so it doesn't cover all edge cases.

My next idea was to use `git rev-list --count <branch>` and count the number of commits on a specific branch, and if the result was 0, I would ignore the branch. However I can't seem to figure out how to get all remote commits pushed specifically to one remote branch, including those which have eventually been merged.

Does anyone have a good way to tell if a branch is newly created with zero commits pushed to it?

Comment: Branches cannot be created without having commits on them. All a branch is is a pointer to a commit. By definition they have at least 1 commit.

Answer (score 2):

As [meager pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68947101/git-command-to-check-if-a-remote-branch-is-brand-new-or-has-had-any-commits-to-i#comment121850146_68947101), all Git branches have at least one commit reachable.  This is because by definition, a branch name contains the hash ID of some (existing, not future) commit.  The hash ID stored *in* the branch name *is* the *last* commit that is to be considered "on the branch".

This fact is why using `git reset --hard HEAD~2` strips off the "last two commits", for instance.  The commits themselves are not changed: before the reset, we might have:

```
...--E--F--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

and then afterward we have:

```
          G--H
         /
...--E--F   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

Commits `G` and `H` remain in the repository, and may or may not be easily find-able using some *other* name.  All commits are always read-only, while branch names are not read-only, so now when we use the name `branch` to find the last commit, the last commit we find is commit `F`.  The two commits that used to be at the end of the branch, are no longer on that branch at all.  If a "bigger picture" went like this:

```
                I--J   <-- develop
               /
...--E--F--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

then, after the `reset`, we have:

```
          G--H--I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--E--F   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

While some people would now say that commits `G-H` "moved" to `develop`, they were *on* `develop` all along.  They are simply *still on* `develop`.  Commits up through `F` are now on *both branches*, whereas before, commits up through `H` were on both branches.

Your goal is therefore impossible in general.  In some specific constrained situations, however, we can tell if a new branch name, just now added, also added any new *commits*, or not.

- We start with this observation: all the commits reachable in the repository are reachable from some name, so `git rev-list --all` finds all commits.
- If some new branch name `B` is going to be added, a pre-receive or update hook will see that the information *about* `B` is that its "old" hash ID is the all-zeros null hash ID, and its "new" hash ID is some hash ID.
- Running `git rev-list $new_hash_id --not --all` *before* branch name `B` is added will enumerate all the commits that will, if / after the addition is accepted, be added to the repository.  (The `$new_hash_id` here must be that from the proposed update.)
- But this technique goes wrong when someone uses `git push` to deliver new commits *and more than one ref-name*, because we can't tell whether the "new" commits will be reachable from the additional names.

We can get fancier and read *all* the input lines in a pre-receive hook.  If the proposed updates are creating two branch names and one tag name (and not updating any existing names and not deleting any existing names), we can enumerate the new commits (all of them) with `git rev-list $n1 $n2 $n3 --not all` where `$n1`, `$n2`, and `$n3` are the proposed new hash IDs.  We can then figure out which of the listed commits are on which of the two new proposed branches, and which if any are reachable via the proposed new tag.  We can then reason from these results.

Things get harder if the proposed update creates two branches, modifies six branches, creates three tags, and deletes one tag, for instance.  You could rack your brain (or perhaps ["wrack your brain"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/rack-vs-wrack)) trying to capture all corner cases here.  Or, you could just use a simple (albeit rude) rule: if you have a pre-receive hook that wants to do this kind of checking, read all the input lines and decide whether:

- you need to do any checking;
- you have an easy case or a hard case

and if you have a hard case, simply reject the push wholesale, after emitting an appropriate error message.  (Rejecting a push *without* an error message is extremely rude, since it gives no clue to whomever is running `git push`.  Rejecting a push with a message like "please create new branches with a separate push for each new branch" is still rude, but at least it gives the other person a chance.)

In any case, think *really hard* about whether what you want to do is a good idea at all.  There's little to be gleaned from most branch names, as they're more or less arbitrary pointers to commits whose spelling-as-a-branch-name is more or less arbitrary, created by some human who's likely to squirt mustard into the USB ports.